# MVC 4 - Database not initialized

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I recently restructured my MVC 4 Application and now face the problem that the database is not being initialized anymore.

In Global.asax, I'm calling the initializer on first start this way:

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(new MyInitializer());
new MyContext().Portfolios.Find(1);
new MyContext().UserProfiles.Find(1);
```

MyInitializer contains a little seed method.

```
public class MyInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(MyContext context)
    {
 ...
```

Initializer and Context are in namespace .DAL which I reference to in Global.asax. The Database is empty and I would expect it to be created, but it doesn't.

It seems like the Initializer is not being called at all..it makes no difference if I set the Initializer to DropCreateDatabaseAlways and I don't get why. Does any of you have an idea or a good link?

Comment: It does not even lead to an error when I set the connection string to something false .. so the mistake must be some basic thing I don't get..

Comment: Did you remember to `context.SaveChanges()` after adding data in the `Seed` method?

Comment: Yes, the Seed method ends  context.SaveChanges(); base.Seed(context);

Comment: Potentially not relevant, but worth checking. Is there actually any code which uses `MyContext` other than in the seed method? If not then the database may not initialise.

Comment: Hm where would I place such a code? On application start, a login-page is displayed and the context is not used as far as i see it.

Comment: But in global.asax as posted above the context is used..

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for my question ... it did not contain the info that was necessary to answer it. When I said that I restructured my project, I should have written instead that I added lots of inheritance where formerly, there was no inheritance. Seems like in OnModelCreating, an entry modelBuilder.Entity(); is needed in order for MVC to consider that entity as included.